# Mkdir in path that is an NFS share doesn't assign directory permissions

Tags: server, nfs, nas

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64) server with a Synology NAS mounted at /mnt/media via NFS.

From a bash shell, I cd into /mnt/media and perform a `mkdir new-folder`

The folder is created but there are no folder permissions assigned.

```
d---------   2 gregory gregory  4096 Mar  4 19:59 new-folder
```

Why ?  I can chmod the directory but this is a real problem for processes that want to create a directory for its use.

EDIT: ls -la /mnt/

```
gregory@backup:~$ ls -la /mnt/
total 120
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root   4096 Jun  9  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x   23 root root   4096 Feb 22 06:49 ..
drwxrwxrwx   17 root media  4096 Mar  4 19:59 media
```

Comment: Seems to a problem with Synology's NFS/ext4 implementation: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=96419#p399404

Comment: please [edit] your post to include the output of `ls -la /mnt/` Thank you for helping us help you!